# CRM_Mailing_BAO_Mailing - Error 500 trying to view Draft, Unscheduled, Scheduled, and Sent Mailings

Tags: civimail, error

- Drupal 7.52
- CiviCRM 4.7.15
- Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)
- PHP/5.5.9-1ubuntu4.20

For the past few versions of CiviCRM I am getting a 500 error when going to:

```
Mailings > Draft and Unscheduled Mailings (/civicrm/mailing/browse/unscheduled)
Mailings > Scheduled and Sent Mailings (/civicrm/mailing/browse/scheduled)
```

**The browser page:**

```
The www.EXAMPLE.org page isn’t working

www.EXAMPLE.org is currently unable to handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 500
```

**Apache logs:**

```
[Mon Jan 30 23:11:31.163855 2017] [:error] [pid 7942] [client xx.xx.xx.xx:36293] PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method CRM_Mailing_BAO_Mailing::getPublicViewUrl() in /home/USER/web/EXAMPLE.org/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Mailing/Selector/Browse.php on line 425
```

I can send a mailing, and it does go out, but as soon as I send it I get the error, and can never see the Scheduled and Sent messages.

I am a capable server administrator, and I've been hosting CiviCRM sites for seven years, but I have no idea how to even begin to debug or fix this error. I keep hoping the error will go away with each CiviCRM update, but it remains. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thank you,
Tony

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just looked at a stock install of Civi 4.7.15, and the `getPublicViewUrl()` method is present in `<civiroot>/CRM/Mailing/BAO/Mailing.php`.  So if you're getting an "undefined method" error, I would assume that your `CRM_Mailing_BAO_mailing` class is getting overridden.  My wild guess is you have an extension installed that isn't compatible with 4.7.

Here's what I would do:

- Ensure that the file `<civiroot>/CRM/Mailing/BAO/Mailing.php` exists, and the line `public static function getPublicViewUrl($id, $absolute = TRUE) {` is present in it.  This is pretty much guaranteed unless you're doing something really wacky, but it's a good sanity check.
- Look for any PHP overrides you might have.  Go to **Administer menu » System Settings » Directories** and locate both your "extensions" and "PHP overrides" directory.
- Go into your PHP overrides directory.  Is there a subdirectory `CRM/Mailing/BAO`?  If so, and it has a file `Mailing.php`, then you need to figure out why.  The resolution should be either to remove the override, or to copy the latest version of `Mailing.php` into the folder and incorporate your override.  PHP overrides are difficult to maintain because they're not upgrade-safe; if you have one, I suggest finding a way to remove it.
- Any of your extensions may also have a `CRM/Mailing/BAO` subfolder.  If so, identify if you can disable that extension.  If not, you may want to follow up, either in the comments to this answer, or with the extension author.